# Check if an object exists in a list of objects in jsp in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

FeatureDetail.java

```
public class FeatureDetail{
    private String featureId;
    private String featureName;
    // Their getter and setter methods.
    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    return featureId.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    FeatureDetail other = (FeatureDetail) obj;
    if (featureId == null) {
        if (other.featureId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!featureId.equals(other.featureId))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

I have the following class (IndexAction.java)

```
class IndexAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<FeatureDetail> selectedFeatures;
    private List<FeatureDetail> features;
    // Getter and setter methods for features and selectedFeatures
}
```

features is a list of all the features.
selectedFeatures is a list of all the selected features.
Both the lists have FeatureDetail objects.

In my jsp index.jsp

```
<s:iterator value="features" var="feature">
    <label><s:property value="#feature.featureName"/></label>
    <s:if test="#feature in selectedFeatures">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

My problem is, only one checkbox is checked even though selectedFeatures list has two objects(FeatureDetail objects) which are in features.

Actual requirement is, i want the checkboxes to be checked for the values that are in selectedFeatures list.

Comment: `selectedFeatures.contains(feature)` did you try this one ?

Comment: This should work, I'm missing something... +1 btw

Comment: Apart from `Its getter and setter` that I guess is a mistake (both lists should have getters and setters)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I have getters and setters for both the lists.

Comment: @looser selectedFeatures.contains(#feature) is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot. Works like a charm

Comment: Personally, I'd consider doing a bit more work on the back end and just using a normal checkbox list.